# Generate HTML from JSP

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

The basic servlet jsp setup I'm familiar with ....

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(resourceA.jsp);

dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

The problem is, in addition to sending the reply back to the browser (resourceA.jsp), I need to create
a second HTML output from resourceB.jsp, witch in turn will be emailed or used to create pdf document.

This is not done every time, just in specific conditions and by calling

```
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

the second time I get and **IllegalArgumentException**.

I just need a way in generating HTML from jsp (**basically replacing the ${par} values**) and
returning the html as String, no status code or headers, just html and A have nothing to do with B, so Filters will not work.

------ replay to first Answer ----- comment to small --- no formatting

I can't see why this is so difficaled....

***all the magnesium's is there to merge data with HTML content in the***

```
${par}
${par['key']}
<c:if test="${patBoolean}" >
<c:forEach var="pvar" varStatus="s_pvar" items="${parList}">
```

I even created a wrapper to mask getOutputStream() and getWriter(), creating my own PrintWriter

```
public class ResponseWrapper extends HttpServletResponseWrapper{
  private PrintWriter printWriter;

  public ResponseWrapper(HttpServletResponse response){
       super(response);
  }

  public ServletOutputStream getOutputStream() throws java.io.IOException{....}

  public PrintWriter getWriter() throws java.io.IOException {....}

}
```

in getting the result for the resourceB.jsp, but the problem is dispatcher.forward(request, response)
sets isCommitted some ware in the original HttpServletResponse.

Comment: Are you using the second JSP to create a PDF or send an email, from the client or from the server? If you're attempting to do so from the server, I must admit that JSPs are not the right solution, a templating engine would be better suited for this task.

Comment: I just had a look at Velocity... look at the code: 
#foreach( $criterion in $criteria )

.... it mimics jsp's, I need to learn another scripting method with separate pages, no re-use of code... 

it's so simple jsp, attribute, html... I'm doning it already and it works for email & PDF, but the second dispatcher.forward back to the browser, is now the only problem .... there must be away and YES I'm doing it from the SERVER side

Comment: I think you need to look at issuing two HTTP requests, instead of one, especially if you've managed to get the email/PDF part working. There is simply no way for a server to respond with two different types of content, for the same request. It might also help if you can elaborate your use case, since it is a bit difficult to wrap my head around the fact that an email is generated by the server and sent to the client.

Comment: Use case: Internet user register/update details, the request send to server, this will send return and continue with rest of transaction, but if specific conditions occur, the server needs to ALERT someone or keep record (over and above database). This was always done with simple hard-coded messages (custom field merge), but by using the JSP concept, that email can be just as good as the responces witch is driven by JSP's... this is just one. All backend code is +500 command-pattern, beans, database... full trading site.... is driven on JSP and JSON (ajax) responses....

Comment: Given your use case, I firmly believe that you should avoid using JSPs for sending emails and generating PDFs. Simply put, it is an anti-pattern; JSPs are meant to generate HTML that is displayed on the browser, whereas the rest (PDFs in particular) are more or less binary data, delivered to the actual user via a different protocol. Using JSPs just because they appear to be doing the job is quite bizarre; the application server (the JSP compiler in particular) was not meant to be used that way. In the worst case, you'll bound to get little or no support for production issues.

Comment: I don't generate PDF direcly from JSP, just use YAHP package to convert HTML to PDF. The email is just sending the HTML generated already via normal javax.mail. The PDF and Email is irrelevant, the point is I have a Bean.getName() and JSP with ... <html> ...Hello ${bean.name} ...</html> ... witch translate to ...Hello John....... it is just merging DATA with TEXT, all worked out with no to very little draw back... what is so difficult about that?

Answer (score 1):

**It is very possible.**
Yes maybe it's not the right use case maybe just a workaround but it is **easy**. Who cares.

Once you have a `HttpServletRequest` instance, you can easily construct a mock `HttpServletResponse` to redirect jsp output to a String.

**You need a StringWriter**
In order to get the JSP output you need a `StringWriter`.

```
StringWriter sw=new StringWriter();
```

**Wrap it**
JSP parser or something need a `PrintWriter`.

```
PrintWriter pw=new PrintWriter(sw);
```

**Construct a mock response**
You can't reuse an existing `HttpServletResponse` easily, so build your own.

```
HttpServletResponse res=new HttpServletResponse() {

        @Override
        public PrintWriter getWriter() throws IOException {
            // return your own writer!
            return pw;
        }

}
```

You have to implement other methods too but just use your IDE's quick fix and leave them default.
**Generate it**
`something.jsp` should be an existing one.

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/something.jsp").forward(request,res);
```

**Get the output**
This would print the JSP output to server console.

```
System.out.printf("{%s}",sw.toString());
```

**Continue with the real response**
Using servlets you should continue to deal with the real `HttpServletResponse` just like you haven't generate the JSP before. While in Spring there's no real `Response` to care about.

Till now I still cannot mock a Request as well as Response that works. But with a mock Response it's already enough to solve this question.

Answer (score 0):

JSP is not the thing to do here.  Have a separate process that fills out a Velocity template (for email) or generates a PDF using XSL-FO or iText and leave JSP out of it.  It's a completely separate use case from sending back an HTTP response.

Comment: I can't see why this is so difficaled....
all the magnesium's is there to merge data 
with HTML content in the... see edited post

Comment: @nico, it's difficult because the server has committed the response to the client for the original request; once the response has been committed, you cannot write another response or modify the original. You cannot alter that behavior of the server - that's how the internet works.

Comment: (+1) for the Velocity suggestion.

Comment: I'm not trying to alter the server (Tomcat), all I need is to re-use the BIG-BIG set of code to merge data and text (html in this case), dynamical. It's there, why reinvent the wheel. I don't want to manipulate the response to the browser at all... if I can clone the HttpServletResponse and disconnected it from the reply it will also work.